# Is $\int {a-b}$ more precise than $\int a - \int b$ when dealing with approximated integrals?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am currently dealing with some numeric integrals (you would have guessed it, applied to programming), and I wondered wether calculating the difference of two integrals was less precise than integrating the difference. I am using a fairly simple trapezoidal method for approximating integrals.
I would expect it to be the case, at least with floating point arithmetic, when dealing with small variations over large areas. But is it true in more situations?

To put it differently, I am trying to determine if *computing* $\int {a-b}$ is systematically more precise than approximating $\int a - \int b$

What do you think?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I'm not a numerical analyst but I would think that computing an approx. of a single integral is more precise than computing the difference between 2 approx. values of 2 integrals simply because the errors may add up in this case (if you have a "large" positive error for $\int a$ and a "large" negative error for $\int b$, for example).

Comment: @paf: I don't agree, because numerical quadrature is (usually) a linear operator in the integrands $a$ and $b$ and convergence estimates are obtained performing Taylor expansion of the integrand (which is a linear operator as well)

Comment: It depends on $a$ and $b$. Approximation error usually depends on the higher order derivative of the integrated function. On other hand if $\int a \approx \int b$, you loose precision due to cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

Computing $\int a - b \, \mathrm{d}t$ is not systematically more precise that computing $\int a \, \mathrm{d}t - \int b \mathrm{d}t$.

WLOG, assume both $a$ and $b$ are non-negative on the integration domain. Then computing $\int a - \int b$ is equivalent to the $+/-$ summation method discussed in [Higham](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0914050). As Higham shows, "this '+/-' method does not reduce the amount of cancellation--it simply concentrates all the cancellation into one step. Second, cancellation is not a bad thing per se;
the problem with cancellation is that it brings into prominence any loss of significant digits suffered earlier in the calculation."